# Changing CSS Style of Element on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Javascript newbie here.

I have an element called 'up_arrow" (picture of an up arrow). I want a script that shows the arrow on desktops but not on mobile devices. So I attempted to use the following script:

```
<script>
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test( navigator.userAgent )){
    document.getElementById('up_arrow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

The up arrow image shows on my computer, but it also shows on my Android phone. Can someone please explain to me what error I made in my coding?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
I have include the element 'up_arrow's code

```
<a href="#header-wrapper"><img id="up_arrow" class="uparrow" alt="uparrow" src="images/uparrow.png"></a>
```

Comment: what does it mean to have the element "called" `up_arrow`?

Comment: where did you put the script, head or body?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I think OP means that the `<img>` tag has an attribute `id="up_arrow"`.

Comment: @TedHopp I just want to make sure that's what it is, because his element selector is not working if it's not the `ID`

Comment: I have just included the 'up_arrow' element

Comment: @Derek I put the script in the header.

Comment: try to wrap your code by body onload.

Comment: Make sure that your element is in the body before you try to fetch it using `getElementById()`. You should add the script tag in body after making sure the img tag is present on the page.
Other than this you code is fine. 
Did you debug it further to the point where you know the problem is at `document.getElementById()` or in the true/false condition?

Comment: I have not debugged it. But I do have any script that hides the arrow from view when at a certain part of the page and makes the arrow visible when at another part of the page. This code works perfectly AND it is also in the header.

Comment: What does the console say? Any errors? Another thing that came to my mind: Some browsers (Some DOCTYPES too? Never mind...) require JavaScript tags to have the `type` attribute. Try changing your script's start tag to `<script type="text/javascript">`. Not sure, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @FabianLauer Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Did you add a `visibility: visible!important` somewhere?

Comment: Does your console gives any error? 'style' of null or something?

Comment: Hold on. Now it's gone.

I believe my problem must have been the text/javascript...

Comment: Or something.... I really don't know. That's really weird how it just disappeared like that.

Comment: There has to be a reason for it to start working now. Always remember that it may seem that the browser is behaving randomly, but generally this will not be the case. It will most likely be something you have written in a particular way which is interpreted by the browsers differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use responsive design approach in your css stylesheet. For example:

```
#up_arrow {
  visibility: hidden
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {
  #up_arrow {
    visibility: visible 
  }
}
```

will hide the up_arrow on "small screen devices" (define the "mobile device" by screen size, not the user agent).
For more details, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use style.display="none" instead of visibility

Comment: That depends... `display: none` will take the element out of float, whereas `visibility: hidden` will only make it fully invisible(like `opacity: 0` would do).